# Access violation when accessing vector through atomic::load()

Tags: c++, vector, atomic

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>

struct foo{
    std::vector<int> bar;
};

int main(){
    std::atomic<foo> theFoo;

    theFoo.load().bar.push_back(30);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me an error with the message "Access violation" when calling line 12. What am I doing wrong? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: You can't use `foo` with `std::atomic` because it isn't trivially copyable.

Answer (score 3):

You're violating the rules. 29.5/1 says:

> There is a generic class template `atomic<T>`. The type of the template argument `T` shall be trivially copyable (3.9). [*Note:* Type arguments that are not also statically initializable may be difficult to use. — *end note*]

The class `foo` is most definitely not trivially copyable.